# weak object has gone away_what does it mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, weak-references

I am using tensorflow for a problem where there is a function which is called once and it works correctly but the second time it is called the error " weak object has gone away" comes up which I don't understand what it means and where the problem might be.

The full trackback is as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _hash_fix(self, elem)
    108     try:
--> 109       hash(elem)
    110     except TypeError:

TypeError: weak object has gone away

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f1a95ac20255> in <module>
----> 1 default_settings['sur_model'].predict_with_grad(np.atleast_2d(xx))

<ipython-input-5-7e554cb74b1d> in predict_with_grad(self, x)
    127 
    128         with tf.GradientTape() as t:
--> 129             m, v = self.predict(x)
    130             dmdx = t.gradient(m, x)
    131         with tf.GradientTape() as t:

<ipython-input-5-7e554cb74b1d> in predict(self, X)
    116         """
    117 
--> 118         X_embed = self.embedding_model(X)
    119         #print('X_embed',X_embed)
    120         m, v = self.Pr_model.predict_y(X_embed)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    889           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    890               self._compute_dtype):
--> 891             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    892           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    893           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    492       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    493       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 494       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    495       if self._created_variables:
    496         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1820   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
-> 1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2117 
   2118     with self._lock:
-> 2119       graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2120       if graph_function is not None:
   2121         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __eq__(self, other)
    115 
    116   def __eq__(self, other):
--> 117     return self._fields_safe == other._fields_safe  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    118 
    119 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _fields_safe(self)
     91   def _fields_safe(self):
     92     """Hash & equality-safe version of all the namedtuple fields."""
---> 93     return (self._hash_fix(self.input_signature), self.parent_graph,
     94             self.device_functions, self.colocation_stack,
     95             self.in_cross_replica_context)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _hash_fix(self, elem)
     99     # Descend into tuples
    100     if isinstance(elem, tuple):
--> 101       return tuple(self._hash_fix(i) for i in elem)
    102 
    103     if isinstance(elem, set):

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in <genexpr>(.0)
     99     # Descend into tuples
    100     if isinstance(elem, tuple):
--> 101       return tuple(self._hash_fix(i) for i in elem)
    102 
    103     if isinstance(elem, set):

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _hash_fix(self, elem)
     99     # Descend into tuples
    100     if isinstance(elem, tuple):
--> 101       return tuple(self._hash_fix(i) for i in elem)
    102 
    103     if isinstance(elem, set):

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in <genexpr>(.0)
     99     # Descend into tuples
    100     if isinstance(elem, tuple):
--> 101       return tuple(self._hash_fix(i) for i in elem)
    102 
    103     if isinstance(elem, set):

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tf-tRAPLeXL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _hash_fix(self, elem)
    110     except TypeError:
    111       v = elem()
--> 112       return (v.__class__, tensor_spec.TensorSpec(v.shape, v.dtype))
    113 
    114     return elem

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I find it rather strange and haven't found a clue to know from where I should fix it.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide/add the code snippet that returned this error?

Comment: @stephen_mugisha the problem there are a lot of codes I wrote that result to this

Comment: Ok i'll try to answer based off the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your using `tf.function /@tf.function` somewhere in your code and you may be trying to redefine an object which results in `@tf.function` not retracing your graph. This is because the two objects share the same trace and that even using different parameters has no effect. the following snippet reproduces the behavior described above

```
import tensorflow as tf
@tf.function
def square(x):
    return x**2

a = square(tf.Variable(2))
print(a)
a = square(tf.Variable(3))
print(a)
```

However, if you want different objects to have different traces .i.e not share traces, you may use different `@tf.function` objects as below;

```
@tf.function
def square1(x):
    return x**2

@tf.function
def square2(x):
    return x**2

print(square1(tf.Variable(2)))
print(square2(tf.Variable(3)))
```

For more details, checkout the [official_documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function). Hope this helps

Comment: Nice, deactivating the @tf.function worked, thanks, it seemed a very uncommon error that I wouldn't have been able to figure out where it is from by my own. Do you also know if there is a way to make deepcopy or multiprocessing possible for these tensorflow models?

Comment: I don't know about making deepcopies of a model.

Comment: Ok but what if I need several independent versions of the function? Manually copy/pasting the function and renaming like that is kind of an awful solution for any non-trivial function. Isn't there some better way to force the graph to get retraced? I am doing some fitting of a function and need to repeat the fit for various different inputs. Can I put the whole thing inside another function to dynamically generate the tf.function on command? I guess I'll try that... ok no, doesn't work. What else can be done then?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone ends up here like me, this error can also occur if you use imageio. Calling the function twice with an imageio object will give you this error. But if you convert it to a numpy array it will work

```
import tensorflow as tf
import imageio

@tf.function
def square(x):
    return x**2

# wont work
# a = square(imageio.imread('myimage.png'))
# a = square(imageio.imread('myimage.png'))

# will work!
a = square(np.asarray(imageio.imread('myimage.png')))
a = square(np.asarray(imageio.imread('myimage.png')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the answer, I was very unsatisfied with having to copy/paste the python function to fix this problem. Fortunately, it seems that simply ditching the decorator method and calling `tf.function` as a function also solves the problem:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2

traced1 = tf.function(square)
traced2 = tf.function(square)

print(traced1(tf.Variable(2)))
print(traced2(tf.Variable(3)))
```

This is much more programmatic and means you don't have to do any silly copy/pasting of code just to re-run something.